# How to install VTK5 on Archlinux?

Tags: vtk, archlinux

I need to run a program which use VTK5 on my Archlinux PC, but I found it really hard to install VTK5, there is only VTK6(not compatible with VTK5) in official repo, and when I try to install it from AUR, it returns "Makepg was unable to build vtk5", then I try to install through source code, the result is that I was unable to install the VTK Python module...

Is there anybody who has any experience or idea about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not installed on Archlinux specifically, but on different linux machines. If you compile from source and are interested in python, remember to select the option python wrapping when running cmake. Btw, once built, you will have to update both the pythonpath and the ldlibrarypath.

You can also have a try at enthought canopy, which distributes a complete installation with numpy, scipy, vtk http://docs.enthought.com/canopy/quick-start/install_linux.html

Comment: I tried `cmake  VTK_WRAP_PYTHON=ON BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON ..`(while `mkdir build | cd build` first), then I `make -j4`, it returns that `[ 73%] Rendering/CMakeFiles/vtkRendering.dir/build.make:5671: recipe for target 'Rendering/CMakeFiles/vtkRendering.dir/vtkXOpenGLRenderWindow.cxx.o' failed
` I am not sure where is the error...

Comment: Then sorry i dont know... i didnt have this problem. Maybe  http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/paraview/2007-October/005971.html helps?

Comment: Really appreciate for your answer, but now I decide to use a Ubuntu machine on which the problem can be easily solved with `sudo apt-get install libvtk5-dev`.